# SQLite for Swift: INSERT INTO SELECT is not working

Tags: swift, sqlite

i have a table MainTable containing a column 'variantID' (String) and a empty table called Variants with primary key 'id' (String) and a few other columns with default values. Now i want to create an entry for every variantID. Here is my code

```
func fillVariants() {
    do {
        let stmtString = "INSERT INTO Variants(id) SELECT DISTINCT variantID FROM MainTable"
        try self.connection?.prepare("\(stmtString)")
    } catch {
        print("Could not insert Variants.")
    }
}
```

the function does not catch any error, but the Variants table is still empty. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: @Gisno which library you are using for performing SQLite operations?

Comment: this one: https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift

Comment: any update on answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `execute` for executing raw sql

```
try self.connection?.execute("\(stmtString)")
```